# On page load using Asp.net mvc angularjs (data-ng-Init)

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Hi i have create that sending request to asp.net web api when page loads using angularjs 'data-ng-Init' this is working on localhost and local IIS server but it is not working on Server System IIS server. for explanation purpose

**html code**

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div ng-if="status==true">
       <input type="date" ng-model="date" ng-change="getyear("@Url.Content("~/api/getDate")")" />
       <div data-ng-Init="GetData('@Url.Content("~/api/getDate")')></div>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="status==false">
       <input type="date" ng-model="date" ng-change="getYear("@Url.Content("~/api/getYear")")" />
       <div data-ng-Init="GetYear('@Url.Content("~/api/getYear")')></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**AngularJS**

```
$scope.getData=function(link){
      $http({
             method:'POST',
             url:link,
             data:{data:'somedata'}
             }).then(function(result){
                ...result
             },function(error){
                ...error
      });
}]);
```

like this i have return.

i can send request without writing the code in function, but i have two div's tag which is written in if condition any one div tag will executes.

And the code was working when ng-change means when change the date its working fine but only not working when page loads 'data-ng-Init'.

> I am Getting Error like this "192.124.213.12/projectname/api/getDate/ 500 Internal Server Error"

Comment: "500 Internal Server Error" means the server-side code crashed. To find out **why** it crashed, examine the server logs. Once you've found the exception details, you'll have a better idea of how to deal with it.

Comment: but its working on ng-change, why it is not working ng-init. i'm sorry to ask this where to find the server log

Comment: Look in the windows event viewer to begin with.